# Sharing a calculated value between lists

Tags: sharepoint-designer, calculated-column

I have to create two separate lists.  One list is an overall master table of data, the other is a list that shows the total for selections on the master.  What I need to do is to calculate out the number of "Yes" options that are taken from each column and then put that data into the second list.  What would be the easiest way to do this?  There are five total columns that have Yes or No answers that need to be counted.  The reason for doing this is that the quick look up list needs to be updated when the master is updated.  I have some ideas, but they are all pretty complex.  Any advice would be great.  I am using SharePoint 2007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to a blog that I think will get you half way there:  http://blog.metrostarsystems.com/2012/12/03/jennys-sharepoint-tip-sum-calculated-columns/

The problem will then be copying the item over to the new list and off the top of my head, without Visual Studio, you will have to use jquery and SPServices/lists.asmx to get the item over to the new list.

Comment: This is a good start.  I think using SPAPI to transfer the values will probably be my best bet.

Comment: Since you are in SP20007 and don't have access to the client object model, I would highly recommend using [SPServices on Codeplex](http://spservices.codeplex.com/).  This is basically a wrapper for pretty much all of the SP webservices and is pretty simple to use if you know jquery.  But if you can work in VS and you are comfortable doing so, then go that route.